# is there anyone who can help me why ShowDetail.html page is not opening when i am submitting my form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I don't know why this is not working, when I am submitting the code the shoDetail.html page is not opening. I had also tried by entering the complete URL but still not working. 
I am sharing the code with you.

```
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" >
<button  type="submit" style="margin-left: 70% " class ="btn btn-primary" class="form-control" formaction="showDetail.html">submit</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn" >cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

I had tried with formation on form tag and also tried to call showDetail at onsubmit event .
there is no error shown on the console while I am inspecting the code.

Comment: I had tried with formaction on form tag but not working

Comment: Can you show the whole form where action attribute can be seen.

Comment: The value should be shoDetail.html

Answer (score 0):

**add this attribute in place of 'formaction'**

```
<button onClick="location='./showDetail.html';">submit</button>
```

**I hope it worked :)**